# Button that refreshes the page on click

Tags: javascript, button, refresh, reload

I need a button that will refresh the page on the user's click. 
I tried this:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="reload">
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="refresh">
```

But neither worked.

Answer (score 368):

Use `onClick` with `window.location.reload()`, e.g. :

```
<button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh Page</button>
```

Or `history.go(0)`, e.g.:

```
<button onClick="history.go(0);">Refresh Page</button>
```

Or `window.location.href=window.location.href` for '**full**' reload, e.g.:

```
<button onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Refresh Page</button>
```

---

[The Button element - developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: what's the difference between these three options?  Is one better than the others for some situations?

Comment: 1st and 2nd are different ways to reload the page, but the 3rd does a "_full_" reload, meaning that if there's any text on input forms. they'll emptied.

Comment: Tested the suggestions and noticed that it needs to be logged in to work.
Is impossible to make a button that does a reload on the page even if the user is anonymous?

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```js
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onClick="refreshPage()">Refresh Button</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

I noticed that all the answers here use inline `onClick` handlers. It's generally recommended to keep HTML and Javascript separate.

Here's an answer that adds a click [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) directly to the button. When it's clicked, it calls [location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) which causes the page to reload with the current URL.

```js
const refreshButton = document.querySelector('.refresh-button');

const refreshPage = () => {
  location.reload();
}

refreshButton.addEventListener('click', refreshPage)
```

```css
.demo-image {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="refresh-button">Refresh!</button>
<img class="demo-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<a onClick="window.location.reload()">Refresh</a>
```

This really works perfect for me.

Answer (score 8):

Only this realy reloads page (Today)

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="location.href=location.href">
```

Others do not exactly reload. They keep values inside text boxes.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by: "***Only this realy reloads page (Today)***" ?

Comment: "Today" means the day I wrote it (because every day something changes). "Only this" is relevant to answers given above by Pedro Lobito.

Comment: All answets on SO are "***as of today***" and subject to be updated if anything changes, that's the nature of almost anything in life, not only answers.

Comment: Still good advice today:) Had a form that was not getting updated using other page refresh methods, this one solved the issue for me! Thank you, was pulling my hair out...

Comment: Hi all, which one of the examples does a forced reload of the page, i.e. not using the browser cache? Or do they all?

Answer (score 7):

Though the question is for `button`, but if anyone wants to refresh the page using `<a>`, you can simply do

```
<a href="./">Reload</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

button that refresh the page on click

Use onClick button with window.location.reload():

```
<button onClick="window.location.reload();">
```

Answer (score 5):

just create the empty reference on link such as following

```
 <a href="" onclick="dummy(0);return false;" >
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<button onclick=location=URL>Refresh</button>
```

This might look funny but it really does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

```
<button onClick="window.location.reload();">Reload</button>
```

Or you can also use

```
<form action="<same page url>" method="GET">
<button>Reload</button>
</form>
```

Note: Change `"<same page link>"` with the url of same page you want to reload.
for example:
`<form action="home.html> method="GET">`

Answer (score 2):

Use this its work fine for me to reload the same page:

```
<button onClick="window.location.reload();">
```

Answer (score 1):

When designing a website, it's always important to consider the best practices for Content Security Policy and disabled JavaScript users.

-Inline scripts like `onClick` are a vulnerability.

-Ignoring the `<noscript>` tag and styling your elements hidden then using JS to change the `display:` back to its respective styling forces the user to enable JS.

This is the simplest solution for all situations.

```
<a href="/">Reload Page</a>
```

Comment: JavaScript in itself is a vulnerability, doesn't matter if it's inline, or in a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script>
    function locationreload() {
        location.reload();
          
    }
   </script>

    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to refresh your page?') , locationreload();" class="btn btn-success">Refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a form reset:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset Form Values"/>
```

or to reset other aspects of the form not handled by the browser

```
<input type="reset" onclick="doFormReset();" value="Reset Form Values"/>
```

Using jQuery

```
function doFormReset(){
    $(".invalid").removeClass("invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to use JavaScript, so I figured out a way using a "hidden form." Here's an example:

```html
<form method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

  <input type="submit" value="Read">
  <input type="submit" value="Reload" form="hidden_form">
</form>

<form id="hidden_form" method="get"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="refresh">refresh</button>
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

"reload" and "refresh" aren't JavaScript functions.
Try using the following code:

```js
function reload() {
  window.location.refresh();
}
```

```html
<button onClick="reload()"></button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).