# Refresh page and run function after - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reload

I'm trying to refresh a page and then run a function once the refresh has been completed. However the code I have now, runs the function and then it only refreshes it, meaning I lose what the function did. Is there a way to solve this?

**My code**

```
function reloadP(){
    document.location.reload();
    myFunction();
}

<button onclick: "reloadP()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Check out `onbeforeunload` and `onload ` events

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to call `myFunction()` when the page is loaded.

```
window.onload = myFunction;
```

If you only want to run it when the page is reloaded, not when it's loaded for the first time, you could use `sessionStorage` to pass this information.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
    if (reloading) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
        myFunction();
    }
}

function reloadP() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    document.location.reload();
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5sL3hd74/)

Comment: no it basically loads the function code then it refreshes so you only see a the function output for about half a second

Comment: I don't understand. The function runs *after* the refresh, not before it.

Comment: What does `myFunction()` do?

Comment: I will give this a go and it creates a table

Comment: Is the button inside a `<form>`? Change it to `<button type="button"`, otherwise it will submit the form.

Comment: is there a reason this code only works in firefox and not explorer or chrome?

Answer (score 5):

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("welcome").textContent = "Welcome back!";
}

window.onload = function() {
    var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
    if (reloading) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
        myFunction();
    }
}

function reloadP() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    document.location.reload();
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5sL3hd74/

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Barmar answer... In case you'd like to use session storage only when a button in the page is clicked and **not** when reloading with the *browser button*, you can use `sessionStorage.clear()` or `sessionStorage.removeItem()` once you've executed the function after loading the window.

So, let's say we have:

```
let restart = sessionStorage.getItem("restart")
```

Set **restart boolean** to true as a session storage and reload:

```
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   sessionStorage.setItem("restart", "true")
   location.reload()
})
```

Once the **window is reloaded** we can execute the following function:

```
window.onload = () => {
  if(restart){
    // Do something
    sessionStorage.clear() // This cleans all the session storage
    
    // If you want to  remove ONLY the item from the storage use:
    // sessionStorage.removeItem("restart")
  }
};
```

So, if now the user reloads the page with the browser button it will reload with the session storage cleaned. Meaning, no functions will be executed after window load.

Comment: using `sessionStorage.clear()` does not seem to be the right choice. Because (as mentioned in the reply), it would not only erase our item but also clear other possibly stored items. So, using `sessionStorage.removeItem()` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used Barmar's solution. I have a modal popup form, i want to submit the form then automatically refresh the page and finally success message on reloaded page.

```
var form = document.getElementById('EditUserInfosForm')
form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    document.location.reload();
})

window.onload = function () {
    var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
    if (reloading) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
        $('#success-message-modal').modal('show')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest approach.

## HTML Button

Reload button ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29884677/7389293)):

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh Page</button>
```

## JS Code

Run your code after reload:

```js
// index.js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    YourFunction(); // already declared somewhere else
});
```

You may not use `event` variable at all.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event#examples