# how to check if page is resized or refreshed

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        checkScrollHeight();
    });
});

    function checkScrollHeight() {
        let stickyNavbar = document.getElementById('sticky-navbar');
        let currentPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        let bannerHeight = document.getElementById('banner-height').offsetHeight || document.getElementById('banner-height').clientHeight;

        if(currentPosition > bannerHeight) {
            stickyNavbar.style.display = "block";
            return;
        } else {
            stickyNavbar.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Currently the function is working when the user resizes the page, but how can I write the code so the function will be called after reloading the page? The navbar should be displayed when it passes the specific height of the banner which will dynamically change based on the screen width.

Comment: There is no difference between reloading a page and loading it the first time.

Comment: you could store something in session storage to detect refreshing.

Comment: why won't use css media queries for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh page and run function after JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904975/refresh-page-and-run-function-after-javascript)

Comment: @SLaks, but the function would not be executed only after resizing the screen.

Comment: @SLaks Not related to the question but there is some difference: Cache images and files - js, css, fonts...

Answer (score 0):

Just call it. All your JS is executed afresh when the page reloads.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScrollHeight );

checkScrollHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies, if you are using only js here.
Like personal lands on page store cookie.
After reloading check the cookie.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
Use this functions for set and get cookies