# when entered in inputbox page refresh according to the entered value

Tags: php

I want when entered in **input box**, page refresh according to the entered value.

Actually enter the number 2 when I refresh the page twice.
This is my code, however, my code runs only once.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['refresh-time'])){  
    $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['refresh-time'];
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $_SESSION['value'] ; $i++ ){
        $value = $_SESSION['value'];
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Refresh: $value ; URL=$url");
    }

}
?>

<form class="form-inline" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">referesh number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refresh-time">
</div>  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i> apply</button>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried to set input `type="number"` ?

Comment: Try with javascript [Button that refresh page on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884654/button-that-refresh-page-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use

```
header("Refresh: {$value} ; URL={$url}");
```

or

```
header("Refresh:" . $value ." ; URL=" .$url);
```

but, you use the $_SESSION['value'] value only when posted a new one, and then you are overwriting the $_SESSION['value'] everytime, so why use $_SESSION?

Also, if the headers are already set (something was "printed") this is not going to work. I don't understand de use of this code, but anyway, a javascript approach would be better.

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo $url;?>";
```