# How can I load JavaScript page refresh after click on link class?

Tags: javascript

How I load JavaScript main page refresh only after user clicks on specific link class? I need it when the user clicks on the link, some JavaScript (or PHP, or whatever) detects that he has clicked on this class link and only then refreshes the origin page.

Example:

When user clicks on:

```
<a class="link_id" target="blank" href="http://externallink.com">external link</a>
```

JavaScript below auto load:

```
window.location.reload();
```

PS: I can not use the `onclick="location.reload()"`, button or similar method for many reasons (my project particularities, for example). Moreover, my HTML will be extensive and dirty. Moreover, it is not safe for the project to let users know that the refresh is through the onclick direct on link. So I'm looking for another way to do this.

Comment: `PS: I do not want to use "onclick" method.` --- why not? That's literally what it was made for.

Comment: I need load javascript code based in link id. Onclick method does not fit my context and purpose. Thanks.

Comment: `Onclick method does not fit my context and purpose` --- not true. Literally exactly your context and purpose

Comment: "How I load javascript page refresh only after user click in specific link" - After the user clicks. That's what onclick is for.

Comment: you could use `javascript:window.location.reload();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button that refresh page on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884654/button-that-refresh-page-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` does exactly what you said. However, if you *really* don't want to use it, you can always do this:

```
<a id="link_id" href="javascript:location.reload()">link</a>
```

As exemplified by this snippet:

```js
let i = 0;setInterval(() => {document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = i;i++}, 50);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">link</a><br>
<span id="span"></span>
```

**EDIT**: Since you actually told me what you wanted in the comments, I present you with code!

Since you only have one element with the ID `link_id` you can do any of the following:

```
<a id="link_id" href="http://link.com" onclick="location.reload()">link</a>
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("link_id").onclick = location.reload;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("link_id").addEventListener("click", location.reload);
```

If you have multiple elements under one ID, you seriously need to reconsider your HTML knowledge

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**: as the air of mystery and vagueness unfolds, I see that you have multiple elements with one ID, or seem to. In that case, use class, and then do this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("<classname>")).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", () => {location.reload();});
});
```

**I REALLY HOPE THIS IS THE FINAL EDIT** - Replace `<classname>` with the name of your class, of course

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("<classname>")).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("reloaded")) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("reloaded", true);
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Check out this jsfiddle - it works: https://jsfiddle.net/gbdu3vpm/1/

Comment: then you can't do it without onclick

Comment: Does not exist a javascript code that allows the "window.location.reload" function only if user clicks on the "link_id" id?

Comment: See the edit, please. However, I did use `onclick`, since **that is your only choice**

Comment: Hi Zevee. 
`document.getElementById("link_id").onclick = location.reload;` loads without clicking the link id.
`document.getElementById("link_id").addEventListener("click", location.reload);` does not work.

Comment: How about the first one? Also, I do not understand what you mean by `clicking the link id`. If you gave some more context, like if you had any event listeners on the element, maybe I could help out more

Comment: Zevee, it's simple: I need it when the user clicks on the link, some javascript (or php, or whatever) detects that he has clicked on this id link and only then refreshes the page.

Comment: Okay. Tell me why `<a id="link_id" href="http://link.com" onclick="location.reload()">link</a>` didn't work. Also, please tell me if you have any event listeners on the id. You're being extremely vague about context here

Comment: It works. But I will have to insert this in all the links. My html will be extensive and dirty. Moreover, it is not safe for the project to let users know that the refresh is through the "onclick" direct. So I'm looking for another way to do this.

Comment: Please see the edit. And **PLEASE** stop being so vague

Comment: Yes Zevee, I have multiple <a> elements with one ID :/ 
Why can not I do this?
Yes, I can use class too.

Comment: Because it's literally not what ID is for. From MDN: "The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which **must be unique** in the whole document." Therefore, your HTML is invalid. Use a class

Comment: Thanks Zevee :) 
I updated my question. Can you update your answer based on my question update?
You can also help me insert a new functionality in this code? I need that `location.reload` happen only once per user browser session.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully for the last time

Comment: Yeah, I know, but they're not really acting that way. Just being extremely vague and confusing and contradicting.

Comment: Thanks @zevee. I just wanted to do a refresh page differently from the traditional way. Sorry if I was vague. I'm sure your answer will help other users who want to make differently. Zuckerberg made different, Bill Gates made different, Steve Jobs made different, now Zevee is helping to make different ;) Thank you!