# Clear the existing dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

When I enter the "reset" command, I want the conversation restart again and clear all the previous dialog, May I ask about how to do it? I had stuck for 2 days.
Thank in advanced.

Here with my source code.

```
bot.dialog('/reset', (session) => {
    session.endDialog();

    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .addAttachment(welcomecard_1.welcomeCard());

    session.send(msg);
})
.triggerAction({
    matches: /^reset$/i
});
```

After I enter the "reset" or "/reset"
the previous conversation [in red color] will remove from the dialog and this channel is using direct line.
[image]

**Updated:**
I had try this code , but not work.

```
bot.use(builder.Middleware.dialogVersion({ version: 1.0, resetCommand: /^reset/i }));
```

Comment: May I know which channel you are connecting with?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Direct Line

Comment: I had use this method but not working . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#delete-data

Comment: Managing state data has nothing to do with the conversation history in the channel client. That's a visual element rendered in the UI. Clearing the conversation history will be the responsibility of the client application. Did you build the Direct Line client yourself?

Comment: I did not build the Direct Line myself.

Comment: Your channel will be webchat, right?

Comment: @NicolasR is directline and publish in web.

Comment: Directline... so you implemented your own webchat? Or is it using Bot Framework's webchat (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)?

Comment: @NicolasR No and using the node js. we still using SDK v3 not yet v4.

Comment: You are talking about the bot's code side, I'm talking about the channel where you interact with your bot. Here you are asking to clean a conversation on a UI, the main point is... what is this UI? Directline is not a UI, it is the communication (used by the Webchat UI, used by custom UI...). And as Kyle said, "Clearing the conversation history will be the responsibility of the client application" so you must tell us what is this client application

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the dialog stack using `session.clearDialogStack()` or `session.endConversation()` or `session.reset()`. Here are the differences between them:

### `session.clearDialogStack()`

- Does nothing extra

### `session.endConversation()`

- Optionally sends a message to the user
- Clears `conversationData` and `privateConversationData`
- Sends an `endOfConversation` event to the channel

### `session.reset()`

- Begins a new dialog

Comment: Are you saying you meant to ask how to clear the conversation history from the channel client?

Comment: Yes. That I means.

Comment: @EngSoonCheah - Is Md Farid Uddin Kiron's answer acceptable?

Comment: No. @Kyle Delaney

Comment: I had use this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#delete-data but its not working.

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777268/2122672